# How to add Drop Down List with Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, python-script-tool, parameters

my code that takes one particular transformation method ("DHDN_to_ETRS") but it doesnt give you opportunity to choose it from drop down list looks like this:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
outWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

try:
    for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

        dsc = arcpy.Describe(infc)

        if dsc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
            print('Koordinate System unbekannt!: ' + infc)
        else:
            outfc = os.path.join(outWorkspace, infc)
            outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference(25832)
            transform_method="DHDN_to_ETRS"
            arcpy.Project_management(infc, outfc, outCS, transform_method)
            print(arcpy.GetMessages())

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex.args[0])
```

Comment: What does DHDN_to_ETRS refer to? A custom transformation built using Create Custom Geographic Transformation tool?

Comment: exactly! And I want that my tool be able to choose between several transformation methods.

Comment: See "value list" here: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm#GUID-3CB5FAF4-43DD-4C84-8AFE-08039A72B3E0

Answer (score 1):

This is done by setting validation code in the script tool properties. You can do this using the interface, or if you need more functionality (ie not hard coded list) you can write python script validation code (the value list linked in the comment above)

Understanding validation in script tools: [ArcMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/understanding-validation-in-script-tools.htm) --- [Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/understanding-validation-in-script-tools.htm)